# d3 ".call" function doesn't work for

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am playing around for a project with d3.js...
I want to add the axes into scale some group of ordinary array data...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first d3.js</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="mySVG"></div>

    <script>       
       var dataArray=[20,40,50,60];
       var width=500;
       var height=500;

       var widthScale=d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0,100])
                        .range([0,width])

       var color=d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0,60])
                    .range(["blue","red"])
        var axis=d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(widthScale);


       //container
        var canvas=d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width",width)
                    .attr("height",height)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform","translate(50,50)");
                    .call(axis);


        var bar=canvas.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(dataArray)
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", function(d){return widthScale(d);})
                    .attr("height",30)
                    .attr("fill",function(d){return color(d)})
                    .attr("y",function(d, i){return i*50;});



    </script>
  </body>
```

here on **.call(axis);**  creates an error  which is "*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token* ." but I think it shouldn't create.

so my question what can I do about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

In the lines

```
.attr("transform","translate(50,50)");
.call(axis);
```

The `.` appears after you terminated with a `;`.